# Why is my header float leaving a margin at the top of the page?

Tags: css, margins

I'm doing a practice site based on a project from Treehouse and I'm having a little problem. I've styled a header element and everything is good with what I've done so far, my only question is when I float the element left I get a margin at the top of the page. Without the float the element butts up against the top of the browser just fine.
What is causing this margin to appear? I'm using normalize.css and my code is below:

```
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <h1>Nick Pettit</h1>
            <h2>Designer</h2>
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </header>




body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

h3 {
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}


header {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Changa One", sans-serif;
    margin: 15px 0;
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 0.8em;
}

h2 {
    font-size: .75em;
    margin: -5px 0 0 ;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some spaces:

- `<h1>` has `margin-top: 15px` (caused by `margin: 15px 0`)
- `<header>` has `padding-top: 15px` (caused by `padding: 5px 0 0 0`)
- (*)`<body>` has `margin-top: 8px` (caused by `margin: 8px` in browser's internal stylesheet)

Removing them produces no space: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VEP5H/)

(*) On Firefox 31. Other browsers may behave differently.